# Error creating an intent on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Using `import android.content.Intent;` from Lompa solve my problem on the main `.java` file and manifest but not in the second `.java` file

Here is the code:

```
package com.tutorial.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        String varString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Test");
        Log.d("HelloWorld - Second Activity", varString);
    }
}
```

Here the errors:

```
G:\Crear_Apps\Projects\HelloWorld\app\src\main\java\com\tutorial\helloworld\SecondActivity.java

Error:(6, 37) error: cannot find symbol class Activity

Error:(8, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(10, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super

Error:(11, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Error:(13, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()
```

---

I was following the steps of a tutorial and gave me an error creating an "intent", I searched solutions but nothing works, idk if it's because Android Studio is bugged or is my error, I restarted Android Studio too but nothing happen.

MyActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Log.d("HelloWorld","onCreate");

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Test","true");

    startActivity(i);
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        String varString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Test");
        Log.d("HelloWorld - Second Activity",varString);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.tutorial.helloworld.SecondActivity">
            </activity>
    </application>
```

Errors I get

```
G:\Crear_Apps\Projects\HelloWorld\app\src\main\java\com\tutorial\helloworld\MyActivity.java
Error:(20, 9) error: cannot find symbol class Intent
Error:(20, 24) error: cannot find symbol class Intent
G:\Crear_Apps\Projects\HelloWorld\app\src\main\java\com\tutorial\helloworld\SecondActivity.java
Error:(6, 37) error: cannot find symbol class Activity
Error:(8, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(10, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(11, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(13, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()
```

Comment: Did you use import android.content.Intent; ?
Be sure that Android Studio autoimport the classes you use.

Comment: Seems like you don't use package imports/don't have appropriate sdk installed. Show us the full code of either of the activities.

Comment: We don't write answers in questions; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Change This*

```
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tutorial.helloworld.SecondActivity">
    </activity>
    </application>
```

*To this*

```
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    </activity>
    </application>
```

*Also try changing this*

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity
```

*To this*

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

*Import*

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..you should use `MyActivity.this` instead of just `this`
Also sync android studio once and clean your project and rebuild it..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Log.d("HelloWorld","onCreate");

    Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Test","true");

   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: sync is the synchronize button?